# How to build Collabora Android only as document viewer that does not include the edit mode to reduce the size?

Tags: android, gradle, cmake

currently I could build Collabora online and embed it as an additional SDK to open some documents inside my Android app. But if I embed this original build, the size will be too big, so I plan to remove the feature that I don’t need like editing mode since I just only need the viewer. Could it be possible to only build Collabora as a document viewer? Thank you for your help.

Below I tried to remove unnecessary resources when building by changing build.gradle in lib folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

// buildhost settings - paths and the like
apply from: 'libSettings.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildDir = "${rootProject.getBuildDir()}/lib"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        resValue "string", "app_name", "${liboAppName}"
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_COMMIT", "\"${liboOVersionHash}\""
        buildConfigField "boolean", "GOOGLE_PLAY_ENABLED", "${liboGooglePlay}"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true

            reset ()
            include 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
//        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/liblo-native-code.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/liblo-native-code.so"

    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation', 'ExtraTranslation'
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "${liboAppName} Debug"
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false // FIXME disabled before we get a good proguardRules for callFakeWebsocketOnMessage calling from C++
            shrinkResources false // FIXME cannot be enabled when minifyEnabled is turned off
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/cpp/lib']
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            buildStagingDirectory "${rootProject.getBuildDir()}/cmake"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'

}

task copyUnpackAssets(type: Copy) {
    description "copies assets that need to be extracted on the device"
    into 'src/main/assets/unpack'
    into('program') {
        from("${liboInstdir}/program/types") {
            includes = [
                    "offapi.rdb",
                    "oovbaapi.rdb"
            ]
        }
        from("${liboInstdir}/program") {
            includes = ["types.rdb"]
            rename 'types.rdb', 'udkapi.rdb'
        }

        into('resource') {
            from "${liboInstdir}/program/resource"
//            includes = ['**']
            includes = ['zh_TW','zh_CN']

        }
    }
    into('etc/coolwsd') {
        from('/android/coolkitconfig.xcu')
        includes = [ 'coolkitconfig.xcu' ]
    }
    into('user/fonts') {
        from "${liboInstdir}/share/fonts/truetype"
        // Note: restrict list of fonts due to size considerations - no technical reason anymore
        // ToDo: fonts would be good candidate for using Expansion Files instead
        includes = [
                "EmojiOne*.ttf",
                "Liberation*.ttf",
                "Caladea-*.ttf",
                "Carlito-*.ttf",
                "Gen*.ttf",
                "opens___.ttf"
        ]
    }
//    into('etc/fonts') {
//        from "${liboSrcRoot}/android/source/"
//        includes = ['fonts.conf']
//        doFirst {
//            // we have changed the filter below; so to always re-generate this
//            // file, delete it first - no idea how to set a dependency on
//            // build.gradle changes :-(
//            file('fonts.conf').delete()
//        }
//        filter {
//            String line ->
//                line.replaceAll(
//                    '@@APPLICATION_ID@@', new String("${liboApplicationId}")
//                )
//        }
//    }
    into('share') {
        from "${liboInstdir}/share"
        // liblangtag data is needed for locales like en-CH
        include 'liblangtag/**'
    }

//    into('share') {
//        from "${liboInstdir}/share"
//        // extensions - for the dictionaries for hunspell
//        includes = ['extensions/dict-de/**', 'extensions/dict-en/**', 'extensions/dict-es/**', 'extensions/dict-fr/**', 'extensions/dict-pt-BR/**']
//        exclude { FileTreeElement details ->
//            !(details.file.isDirectory() ||
//                details.file.name.endsWith('.xcu') ||
//                details.file.name.endsWith('.dic') ||
//                details.file.name.endsWith('.aff') ||
//                details.file.name.endsWith('.xml'))
//        }
//    }
}

task copyAssets(type: Copy) {
    description "copies assets that can be accessed within the installed apk"
    into 'src/main/assets'
//    from("${liboSrcRoot}/instdir/") {
//        includes = ["LICENSE.html", "NOTICE"]
//        rename "LICENSE.html", "license.html"
//        rename "NOTICE", "notice.txt"
//    }
//    from("${liboExampleDocument}") {
//        rename ".*", "example.odt"
//    }
    into('program') {
        from "${liboInstdir}/program"
        includes = ['services.rdb', 'services/services.rdb']
    }
    into('share') {
        from "${liboInstdir}/share"
        // Filter data is needed by e.g. the drawingML preset shape import.
        includes = ['registry/**', 'filter/**', 'gallery/**', 'palette/**']
    }
}

task createFullConfig(type: Copy) {
    description "copies various configuration bits into the apk"
    into('src/main/assets/share/config')
    from("${liboInstdir}/share/config") {
//        includes = ['soffice.cfg/**', 'images_colibre.zip']
        includes = ['soffice.cfg/**']

    }
}

//task copyBrandTheme(type: Copy) {
//    from "${liboBrandingDir}/online-theme"
//    into "src/main/assets/share/theme_definitions/online"
//}

//task copyDocTemplates(type: Copy) {
//    from "${rootProject.getRootDir()}/templates/untitled.odp",
//            "${rootProject.getRootDir()}/templates/untitled.ods",
//            "${rootProject.getRootDir()}/templates/untitled.odt"
//    into "src/main/assets/templates"
//}

task copyKitConfig(type: Copy) {
    from "${file(rootProject.getRootDir()).getParent()}/coolkitconfig-mobile.xcu"
    into "src/main/assets/etc/coolwsd"
    rename { "coolkitconfig.xcu" }
}

task createStrippedConfig {
    def preserveDir = file("src/main/assets/share/config/soffice.cfg/empty")
    outputs.dir "src/main/assets/share/registry/res"
    outputs.file preserveDir

    doLast {
        file('src/main/assets/share/registry/res').mkdirs()
        file("src/main/assets/share/config/soffice.cfg").mkdirs()
        // just empty file
        preserveDir.text = ""
    }
}

task createRCfiles {
    inputs.file "libSettings.gradle"
    dependsOn copyUnpackAssets, copyAssets
    def sofficerc = file('src/main/assets/unpack/program/sofficerc')
    def fundamentalrc = file('src/main/assets/program/fundamentalrc')
    def bootstraprc = file('src/main/assets/program/bootstraprc')
    def unorc = file('src/main/assets/program/unorc')
    def lounorc = file('src/main/assets/program/lounorc')
    def versionrc = file('src/main/assets/program/versionrc')

    outputs.files sofficerc, fundamentalrc, unorc, bootstraprc, versionrc

    doLast {
        sofficerc.text = '''\
[Bootstrap]
Logo=1
NativeProgress=1
URE_BOOTSTRAP=file:///assets/program/fundamentalrc
HOME=$APP_DATA_DIR/cache
OSL_SOCKET_PATH=$APP_DATA_DIR/cache
'''.stripIndent()

        fundamentalrc.text = '''\
[Bootstrap]
LO_LIB_DIR=file://$APP_DATA_DIR/lib/
BRAND_BASE_DIR=file:///assets
BRAND_SHARE_SUBDIR=share
URE_BIN_DIR=file:///assets/ure/bin/dir/nothing-here/we-can/exec-anyway
BAK_EXTENSIONS=${$ORIGIN/lounorc:TMP_EXTENSIONS}
BUNDLED_EXTENSIONS=${$ORIGIN/lounorc:BUNDLED_EXTENSIONS}
BUNDLED_EXTENSIONS_USER=${$ORIGIN/lounorc:BUNDLED_EXTENSIONS_USER}
SHARED_EXTENSIONS_USER=${$ORIGIN/lounorc:SHARED_EXTENSIONS_USER}
UNO_SHARED_PACKAGES_CACHE=${$ORIGIN/lounorc:UNO_SHARED_PACKAGES_CACHE}
TMP_EXTENSIONS=${$ORIGIN/lounorc:TMP_EXTENSIONS}
UNO_USER_PACKAGES_CACHE=${$ORIGIN/lounorc:UNO_USER_PACKAGES_CACHE}
'''.stripIndent()

        bootstraprc.text = '''\
[Bootstrap]
InstallMode=<installmode>
ProductKey=LibreOffice ''' + "${liboVersionMajor}.${liboVersionMinor}" + '''
UserInstallation=file://$APP_DATA_DIR
'''.stripIndent()

        unorc.text = '''\
[Bootstrap]
URE_INTERNAL_LIB_DIR=file://$APP_DATA_DIR/lib/
UNO_TYPES=file://$APP_DATA_DIR/program/udkapi.rdb file://$APP_DATA_DIR/program/offapi.rdb file://$APP_DATA_DIR/program/oovbaapi.rdb
UNO_SERVICES=file:///assets/program/services.rdb file:///assets/program/services/services.rdb
'''.stripIndent()

        lounorc.text = '''\
[Bootstrap]
PKG_BundledUnoFile=$BUNDLED_EXTENSIONS_USER/registry/com.sun.star.comp.deployment.component.PackageRegistryBackend/unorc
PKG_SharedUnoFile=$SHARED_EXTENSIONS_USER/registry/com.sun.star.comp.deployment.component.PackageRegistryBackend/unorc
PKG_UserUnoFile=$UNO_USER_PACKAGES_CACHE/registry/com.sun.star.comp.deployment.component.PackageRegistryBackend/unorc
BAK_EXTENSIONS=${$BRAND_BASE_DIR/program/bootstraprc:UserInstallation}/user/extensions/bak
BUNDLED_EXTENSIONS=${$BRAND_BASE_DIR/program/bootstraprc:UserInstallation}/share/extensions
BUNDLED_EXTENSIONS_USER=${$BRAND_BASE_DIR/program/bootstraprc:UserInstallation}/user/extensions/bundled
TMP_EXTENSIONS=${$BRAND_BASE_DIR/program/bootstraprc:UserInstallation}/user/extensions/tmp
SHARED_EXTENSIONS_USER=${$BRAND_BASE_DIR/program/bootstraprc:UserInstallation}/user/extensions/shared
UNO_SHARED_PACKAGES=${$BRAND_BASE_DIR/program/bootstraprc:UserInstallation}/share/uno_packages
UNO_SHARED_PACKAGES_CACHE=$UNO_SHARED_PACKAGES/cache
UNO_USER_PACKAGES=${$BRAND_BASE_DIR/program/bootstraprc:UserInstallation}/user/uno_packages
UNO_USER_PACKAGES_CACHE=$UNO_USER_PACKAGES/cache
'''.stripIndent()

        versionrc.text = '''\
[Version]
AllLanguages=en-US
BuildVersion=
buildid=''' + "${liboCoreVersionHash}" + '''
ReferenceOOoMajorMinor=4.1
'''.stripIndent()
    }
}

clean.doFirst {
    delete "src/main/assets"
    delete "src/debug/assets"
    delete "src/release/assets"
}

// creating the UI stuff is cheap, don't bother only applying it for the flavor..
preBuild.dependsOn 'createRCfiles',
        'createFullConfig'
//        'copyBrandTheme'

task generateCoolDebugAssets {
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine 'make', '-C', "${rootProject.getBuildDir()}/../../browser", 'clean'
        }
        exec {
            commandLine 'make', '-C', "${rootProject.getBuildDir()}/../../browser", "DIST_FOLDER=${project.getProjectDir()}/src/debug/assets/dist", 'BUNDLE=DEBUG'
        }
    }
}

task generateCoolReleaseAssets {
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine 'make', '-C', "${rootProject.getBuildDir()}/../../browser", 'clean'
        }
        exec {
            commandLine 'make', '-C', "${rootProject.getBuildDir()}/../../browser", "DIST_FOLDER=${project.getProjectDir()}/src/release/assets/dist", 'BUNDLE=RELEASE'
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
//    if (!file("${liboBrandingDir}").exists()) {
//        copyBrandTheme.enabled = true
//    }
//  generateDebugAssets.dependsOn copyDocTemplates, copyKitConfig, generateCoolDebugAssets
//  generateReleaseAssets.dependsOn copyDocTemplates, copyKitConfig, generateCoolReleaseAssets
    generateDebugAssets.dependsOn copyKitConfig, generateCoolDebugAssets
    generateReleaseAssets.dependsOn copyKitConfig, generateCoolReleaseAssets
}
```

When I saw through AAR, the biggest file is liblo-native-so, but I don't know how to make this smaller. I just need it to view the document, so I hope maybe I could reduce the size of library by remove edit mode and use only the viewer.